# How to make sure the sting appear in somewhere in the list

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJH9R.jpg)Write a function that takes,as an argument,a list and a string, and returns a Boolean based on whether or not all of the letters in the string appear somewhere in the list.
For question 3

def findLetters(myList,myString):
    for i in myList:
        if i==myString:
            return True
    return False
 That is what did in python, but if I run python shell it constantly give False.

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] of your code you have created for this so far, and explain what difficulties you are experiencing?

Comment: Looks like homework to me, the question title vs question body has vastly different grammar

Comment: Looks like homework to me as well. Keep in mind that many schools have quite severe policies regarding academic dishonesty.

Comment: def findLetters(myList,myString):
    for i in myList:
        if i==myString:
            return True
    return False

Answer (score 0):

Looks like homework task. It is fairly simple so try it yourself.
Use operator `in` to check if a letter is in a string.

```
if c in string:
    print(c, 'is in', string)
```

Comment: Um... I don't think it is simple as you describe, Can you look at the picture I just submitted? Thank you a loto(*￣▽￣*)ブ

Comment: The problem with your code is that you check if myList contains myString. You need to check if every letter in myString is in the set of letters in myList. So you need to [join](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm) all strings in myList into one, then create a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) from this string. Then for every letter in myString check if it is in your set (use operator 'in')